# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/qpid/proton/engine/Collector in AmqpProviderFactory.createProvider

Tags: java, azure, gradle, amqp

I'm getting the below exception thrown at AmqpProviderFactory.createProvider in qpid-jms-client-0.40.0.jar

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/qpid/proton/engine/Collector
    at org.apache.qpid.jms.provider.amqp.AmqpProviderFactory.createProvider(AmqpProviderFactory.java:69) ~[qpid-jms-client-0.40.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.qpid.jms.provider.amqp.AmqpProviderFactory.createProvider(AmqpProviderFactory.java:31) ~[qpid-jms-client-0.40.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.qpid.jms.provider.ProviderFactory.create(ProviderFactory.java:103) ~[qpid-jms-client-0.40.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.qpid.jms.provider.ProviderFactory.create(ProviderFactory.java:82) ~[qpid-jms-client-0.40.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsConnectionFactory.createProvider(JmsConnectionFactory.java:332) ~[qpid-jms-client-0.40.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsConnectionFactory.createConnection(JmsConnectionFactory.java:203) ~[qpid-jms-client-0.40.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsConnectionFactory.createConnection(JmsConnectionFactory.java:194) ~[qpid-jms-client-0.40.0.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy715.createConnection(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.doCreateConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:365) ~[spring-jms-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.initConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:305) ~[spring-jms-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.getConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:283) ~[spring-jms-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.createConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:224) ~[spring-jms-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:180) ~[spring-jms-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.refreshConnectionUntilSuccessful(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:928) ~[spring-jms-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.recoverAfterListenerSetupFailure(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:899) ~[spring-jms-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1077) ~[spring-jms-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_131]
```

Some of the dependencies I have in the classpath are

- qpid-jms-client:0.40.0
- proton-j:0.31.0
- azure-eventhubs:2.2.0

Is there any other dependency that I should add to this to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proton event collector class is a pretty basic bit of the proton-j library that has been in there for years so my guess is that you don't have the libraries on your classpath that you think you do.  The failure indicates it cannot be found and the only reason for that should be that the library simply isn't there.